# java selenium webDriver : method driver.get(url) doesn't work , the browser is open without url

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

I am new with selenium java.
I wrote my first code to open a page using web driver, the browser chrome opened  without content

```
public class WebdriverDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url = "http://www.google.com";
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(url);
       //i tried  driver.navigate().to(url); either but it's not working the same result !! 
}
}
```

[pom.xml screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuipU.png)

[pom.xml screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jfCd.png)

[Empty browser launch screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE2Ep.png)

Comment: The selenium version you are using(`4.0.0-beta-4`) is too old. Update your `pom.xml` to use a more latest version. Latest selenium version as of today is `4.18.1`. See if that helps.